# Canonical tag makes my site "not indexable" according to an SEO analyst plugin

Tags: seo, google-analytics, canonical-url

SEO Doctor add on says website is not indexable because this page is set to (this is my tag):

```
<link rel="canonical" href="http://example.com" />
```

I have to change meta tags robots `noindex` like that or what is the solution for this?

Comment: Your are using WordPress 2.9 ?

Comment: iam using wordpress 3.7

Comment: Please make your question more clearer. Is your website indexed, have you checked using the site: operator in Google? If it isn't indexed, have you checked the source code to see if there are any robots meta tags in place or anything else preventing indexation? Are you showing your website at the www URL's or without? How are your canonical URL's being set? etc etc. Supply much more information and then we may be able to help you.

Comment: In seo doctor Firefox addon showing not indexable because this page is set to canonical tag without WWW and also using robots.txt User-agent: *
Disallow: /wp-admin/
Disallow: /wp-includes/   some keywords are in 1st position but only SEO doctor says not indexable

Comment: To best answer this, we would really need to be able to view the site in question.

Answer (score 1):

I see this issue on most of blogs. WHEN rel=canonical is enabled will see above error messages.

This doesn't sound like an issue with All in One SEO Pack, it sounds like an issue with **SEO Doctor**.

There's nothing wrong with having the canonical link of a page set to the domain of a page.

**rel=canonical :**

rel=canonical having some problem with non-standard WordPress,but it's fixed in WordPress 2.9.

So if you have any non-standard WordPress pages (created through a plugin or in other dynamic means) it may be possible that it they also contain rel canonical tag added by WordPress, which would prevent the particular pages from being indexed.

If that is the case solution is simple. Just add this to your theme functions.php:

> remove_action('wp_head', 'rel_canonical');